# How to import my old "Facebook Business Page" to "Facebook Business Manager" when the owner of the page is the page itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-business-manager

This is the weirdest.

I created a Facebook Page back in 2011, and I have Admin permissions. So far so good.

Few years ago (before Business Manager existed) I started running ads, and somehow, the page became a "Business" and took ownership of itself. When I open "Page Roles" where it says Owner shows the username of the page instead of my name.

Recently I started a Business Manager account and when I try to import my page, it says "A Page admin needs to approve your request for access.". I am lost on where that request is being sent. It's not in my email and not in the "Page Roles" section, like the Facebook doc says.

I am double sure the Owner of the page is the page itself, because the Business Manager gave me the ID of the "Business" that has to approve my request... and is the ID of my Facebook Page.

I've been searching the internet for days looking for an answer, but no luck. Also, I am trying to reach Facebook Support, but although I am a paying customer seems to be disabled for my account.

Any ideas on what the heck is going on, how to solve it or how to contact Facebook support?

I really need and appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 0):

In 2015 I had an issue with my page (I also ran ads) and contacted gms-emea@fb.com (Facebook Global Marketing Solutions - EMEA). They replied within a week. I don't remember where I found this information, I just looked up my sent mails for you.

EMEA is probably for Europe and Middle East, but you can try anyway. They will probably redirect you to the correct support for your region.

Good luck with your issue!